# LimeJs HTML5 Sound on Chrome breaks my file

Tags: html, google-chrome, limejs

I have just start learning LimeJS, but i have a problem with the sound, when i open it in firefox i have not problem but when i open it in chrome the game stop working and doesnt show, i dont know why, i try to fix it and now i can see the objects but i cant drag them, is like it stop . here is the code, I hope you can help me

```html
//set main namespace
goog.provide('bichos');
 
 
//get requirements
goog.require('lime');
goog.require('lime.Director');
goog.require('lime.Scene');
goog.require('lime.fill.LinearGradient');
goog.require('lime.Sprite');
goog.require('goog.math');
goog.require('lime.GlossyButton');
goog.require('lime.audio.Audio');
goog.require('lime.Layer');
goog.require('bichos.Bug');
 
goog.require('lime.Label');
// entrypoint
bichos.start = function(){
 
        var director = new lime.Director(document.body,480,320);
        director.makeMobileWebAppCapable();
        director.setDisplayFPS(false);
            var scene = new lime.Scene().setRenderer(lime.Renderer.DOM);
        var initialscene = new lime.Scene().setRenderer(lime.Renderer.DOM);
 
    //InitialScene
    var initialLayer = new lime.Layer().setPosition(0,0).setAnchorPoint(0,0);
    var initialContainer = new lime.Sprite().setAnchorPoint(0,0).setPosition(0,0).setFill('#EEE0E5').setSize(480,320);
    var initialTitle = new lime.Label().setText('Welcome').setFontFamily('Arial').setFontColor('#000000').setFontSize(20).setPosition(240,60);
    var startButton = new lime.GlossyButton().setSize(200,60).setPosition(240,150).setText('Start').setColor('#00cD00');
   
    initialscene.appendChild(initialLayer);
    initialLayer.appendChild(initialContainer);
    initialLayer.appendChild(initialTitle);
    initialLayer.appendChild(startButton);
 
   //director
    director.replaceScene(initialscene);
 
    //evento inicial
    goog.events.listen(startButton,['mousedown','touchstart'],function(e){
        e.event.stopPropagation();
        director.replaceScene(scene);
    });
 
    //Grass
    var grass_gradient = new lime.fill.LinearGradient().setDirection(0,0,1,-1).addColorStop(0,'#7CCD7C').addColorStop(1,'#00FF00');
    var grass = new lime.Sprite().setSize(480,320).setPosition(0.0).setAnchorPoint(0,0).setFill(grass_gradient);
 
    //caja
    var box = new lime.Sprite().setAnchorPoint(0,0).setPosition(390,230).setFill('img/Box01.png').setSize(80,80);
 
           
       
    //contar
    var num_bugs_catched = 0;
    var bug_count = new lime.Label().setText('Bug Count: '+num_bugs_catched).setFontFamily('Arial').setFontColor('#000000').setFontSize(20).setPosition(100,300);
 
    scene.appendChild(grass);
    scene.appendChild(box);
 
    //Insectos
    var num_bugs =goog.math.randomInt(10)+1;
    var x,y,bug;
    for(var i = 0; i < num_bugs; i++){
       
        bug = new bichos.Bug();
        bug.crawl();
        scene.appendChild(bug);
   
    //sound
    var bugSound = new lime.audio.Audio('audio/bug.ogg');
 
        //eventos
        goog.events.listen(bug,['mousedown','touchstart'],function(e){
            var drag = e.startDrag();
            drag.addDropTarget(box);
            e.event.stopPropagation();
            bug = this;
            goog.events.listen(drag,lime.events.Drag.Event.DROP, function(e){
                //play sound
                bugSound.stop();
                bugSound.play();
 
                num_bugs_catched++;
                bug_count.setText('Bug Count: '+num_bugs_catched);
                //Desaparecer bichos
                bug.setHidden(true);
                delete bug;
 
               
                    //Tambien se puede usar window.location='';
                if(num_bugs_catched == num_bugs){
                    alert('Has Ganado!');
                    bichos.start();
                }
 
            })
        })
    }
 
   scene.appendChild(bug_count);
        // set current scene active
       
 
}
 
 
//this is required for outside access after code is compiled in ADVANCED_COMPILATIONS mode
goog.exportSymbol('bichos.start', bichos.start);
```